# Why is the applet not playing the audio clip?

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet that is supposed to make a sound on click but it does not work. It would be really helpful if someone could point out what is wrong with the code

```
 AudioClip soundFile1; 
 AudioClip soundFile2;

 public void init()  
 {
      soundFile1 = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"volcanoe.au"); 
      soundFile2 = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"volcanoe.au");
      addMouseListener(this); 
      setBackground(Color.yellow); 
      soundFile1.play(); 
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g)  
 { 
      g.drawString("Click to hear a sound",20,20); 
 }
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)  
 { 
      soundFile2.play(); 
 }
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {} 
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {} 
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {} 
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {}
```

Comment: Try loading the sound into a `javax.sound.sampled.Clip` - it will show useful error information, whereas `getAudioClip` usually won't. BTW Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code on my computer and it worked perfectly. The audio clip stored in **soundFile1** starts playing when the applet is run and when the mouse is clicked, the audio that was already playing stops and the new audio clip in **soundFile2** starts playing. I tested the program with a **.wav** and a **.au** file. The problem in your case might be one of the following:

1. The audio file is missing from the directory where the **.class** file of your applet is. The audio file should be present in the directory of the current project you're working on.
2. There's something wrong with the **.au** file that exists in the current directory. Test the applet with other file formats (eg. **.wav**) or another **.au** file.
3. Something is wrong with your computer's audio codecs. Look up on the internet to fix your audio codecs.
4. Try re-installing your JDK. As [@Tbtimber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6359730/tbtimber) said, try using `getCodeBase()` instead of `getDocumentBase()`. If it works, then update/re-install your JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getCodeBase()` instead of `getDocumentBase()` when you create the AudioClip.